# System.Converter and String.Intern in NET Standard Library 1.6?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am now migrating from .net 4.5.x libraries to .net standard 1.6 libraries. But I don't know how to find packages for
System.Converter, 
String.Intern, 
etc.

Anyone can help me? If those classes are not available in .net standard, which are recommended instead?

Comment: See if this helps - https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Reverse Package Search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) website to find witch package to add.

You can take a look at [.Net Api Catalog](http://apisof.net/) for full .net core reference

- String.Intern Reference page (not available in NET standard) : http://apisof.net/catalog/System.String.Intern(String)
- System.Converter (in NET standard 1.7): http://apisof.net/catalog/System.Converter%3CTInput,TOutput%3E

Comment: Great thanks! Those sites really help me. Which class should I use for String.Intern in .Net standard?

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea to use it. It's also depends on context.